# Iterate with JQuery to a table except the first column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a function for every cell in a table except the first column. Until now, I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("#resultstable tr").each(function () {

    $('td', this).each(function () {
         ....do my staff...
     })

})
</script>
```

This apply the function to every cell in my table. If I change the code to this, I thought that it will work, but it doesn't.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("#resultstable tr").each(function () {

    $('td :not(:first-child)', this).each(function () {
         ....do my staff...
     })

})
</script>
```

Comment: @SterlingArcher If he shown what he tried it doesn't means this question is off-topic...

Comment: Is the first column headers or something that could (perhaps should) be represented by an element other than `<td>`?

Comment: @SterlingArcher If I ask a question without even a piece of code, it will be closed. If I have tried to make it work, is it still off-topic? I don' think so. :)

Comment: @ssube Nope. It is a regular column. I just don't want to apply my function there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just `slice` the elements:

```
$("<selector>").slice(1).each(function () {...});
```

> ## [`.slice( start [, end ] )`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)
>
> Description: Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices.

Another *working* solution would be to build a spaghetti selector using `:not` and `:first`:

```
$("tr").each(function () {
   $("td:not(:first)", this).each(function () {
       // do something
   });
});
```

## Example

```js
var colors = ["#f1c40f", "#2ecc71"];
$("table tr").each(function() {
  $("td", this).slice(1).each(function(i) {
    $(this).css("background", colors[i])
  });
});

setTimeout(function() {
  $("table tr").each(function() {
    $("td:not(:first)", this).each(function(i) {
      $(this).css("background", colors[colors.length - i - 1])
    });
  });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>Age</td>
      <td>Location</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alice</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>Europe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bob</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>Europe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Carol</td>
      <td>15</td>
      <td>Australia</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Does this work for columns too? Because I do want to apply the function on the first column. Not the first row.

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris Ah, I understood you want for rows. Editing...!

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris See the edit. Just `slice` the td elements.

Comment: This works like a charm. Didn't know about the `slice` :) Thank you. For extract info, if I use another number in `slice`, for example 2, this will pass the first two columns, or only the second?

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris Cool! Sure, if you pass the end parameter, you will select a range of elements: from `start` to `end` (zero based). It's like for arrays: `[1, 2, 3, 4].slice(1, 3) => [ 2, 3 ]`.